# How would you implement so each Test class logs output to a separate file?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, logging, testng, junit4

Using Java, with either TestNG or JUnit, if you wanted to log some information gathered during a test to a file, and have each test class (such as **TestClass1.class**) keep a separate output file named after the class like so:

```
TestClass1.log
```

How would you implement this kind of thing?  I know log4j can log the class name in a 'per line' of output in a single file but I want outputs for each class to be in separate files.  Also, log4j can log output to different files based on package name.  Neither of those solutions is what I am looking for because **I want hundreds of tests to create hundreds of log files**.

Answer (score 0):

Using Log4J 1.x, you would have to manually instantiate the Logger in each class, providing a unique file name for each test using a combination of the suite name and class name (assuming each suite has a unique name).

For example in the `setUp()` method of the test class, define the name of the log file:

```
String logFilename = context.getSuite().getName() + "_" + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Then in each class used by the test, manually instantiate the logger and provide the name of the log file you want to use:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private Logger log = null;

  public SomeClass(String logFilename) {
    log = Logger.getLogger(logFilename);
  }
```

But this solution is not very elegant, it requires to pass the file name to all the classes used in the test.

**A better solution:**

If you can upgrade to Log4J 2, it supports writing to separate log files using a `ThreadContext`:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files

I also found this blog post that suggests using LOGBack and its Mapped Diagnostic Context: http://www.nullin.com/2010/07/28/logging-tests-to-separate-files/